# Upgrading from Visual Studio 2008 to 2015 - what worries should I have?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have just taken over ownership of some apps in a new job - mainly consisting of C# & ASP.Net web projects, targeting .Net Framework 3.5.

Currently the company uses VS 2008 for the solutions, I'd like to look at upgrading to 2015.

Can I easily do this without making any breaking changes to the compiled code?  What problems might I expect to come across?
And if all goes ok, how can I be sure that the new compiled code is identical to the old?

Comment: Are you at all familiar with the Visual Studio Conversion Wizard? It kind of "automagically" does this for you

Comment: But what exactly DOES it do ?   Does it do anything that is likely to change the behavior of my code?

Comment: As @Bgl86 says, just do it. Install VS2015 alongside 2008, open the project, compile it and run it and see what happens. The worst that will happen is you have a project that functions incorrectly, in which case get fixing it or stay with 2008 for that project until you have time to fix it.

Comment: Can I easily do this without making any breaking changes to the compiled code? No. There will be some work to get 3.5 to 4.6 as you probably want to get the newest .net framework. Otherwise will be nearly anything to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not interested in changing the framework version just yet, that will be a bigger job for another day for various reasons

Comment: As i see Dai confirmed, nearly anything to be scared about.

Comment: I'd be less worried about what the upgrade would do to your code, and more about what it will do to you as a developer.  Going from VS 2008 to 2015 is a big jump, and there will be a lot to learn.  Make sure to review the What's New articles out there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

VS2015 is almost fully backwards-compatible with VS2008, including support for .NET 2.0 projects, though note a few things:

- .NET Smart Device projects (.NET Compact Framework / Windows CE) are not supported, VS2008 is the last version of VS to support them
- The code editor no-longer indents empty lines (this change was introduced in VS2010 and it still irritates me, personally)
- VS2015 does support round-tripping projects between different versions of VS (i.e. no more forced project upgrades) however this does not stretch back to 2008, I recall 2010 SP1 is the earliest project version you can open in VS2015 without needing to resave
- IDE support for ASP.NET MVC does not include support for generating ASPX-engine views from within the GUI, all menu items create Razor views instead, though the IDE still supports using ASPX views in MVC projects (just copy+paste files, I guess)
- The Help / Documentation system was overhauled in Visual Studio 2010 when they moved from Microsoft Document Explorer to a small web-server that you access with your browser, but user backlash forced Microsoft to add the (new) Microsoft Help Viewer in Visual Studio 2012 - the experience isn't as good as it was under 2008 (in my opinion).

Otherwise, there's nothing else you need to worry yourself over.

That's pretty much it :)

Comment: Thanks !  Thats given me some confidence.  So you are saying the stuff that come out of the 2015 compiler should be the same as in 2008 ?

Comment: @userSteve Correct, if not better, due to improved compiler optimizations

Comment: can I also ask, if I develop in 2015 and other users are using 2013 can we work on the same projects seamlessly ?  Ie are they fully backward and forward compatible?

Comment: @userSteve correct, provided the projects are saved in 2013's format, you can "round-trip" between them, but obviously don't use C# 2015 language features.