# Should I install Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Years ago I forked out big bucks to purchase a full retail version of VS 2008 (inc SQl Server 2005). Then I changed my direction in life and it has been sitting on the shelf ever since.

Now I am wanting to start developing again but wondering if there is any benefit in installing VS 2008 Pro on my Win 10 machine or should I go with the latest free Express versions. I don't want to use any collaboration features. Only small scale stuff - web sites with DB backend.

I was surprised to see copies on Ebay for hundreds of $. Maybe I should sell it.

Very confused about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether you're allowed to re-sell a license like that but.....

Sell it and use the free version if you're not going to be using any of the "pro" stuff.

If you're not allowed to sell it just use the free version, you spent money on something 8 years ago which is now no longer a feasible product.... sorry but you gotta deal with that :P

Comment: Think I will sell it. Chhers

Comment: No problem @Buddy :P (sorry that was just too perfect)

enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not really a programatic questions, I will still answer the best way to my knowledge.

In this case is more about what you prefere and if you're thinking about "re-use" old projects.

[VS 2015 vs 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743772/upgrading-from-visual-studio-2008-to-2015-what-worries-should-i-have)

There you can see the "obvious" changes between 2015 against 2008.
In my personal opinion I would say that you should use free Visual Studio 2015. It offers "smarter" solution and is also well supported. You should only go back to VS2008 If there is something you REALLY need from it.

Comment: I am starting to see the light. Sorry about the inappropriate question.

Comment: No problem. Just click that you have received an answer for your question :)